# difficulty changing elements of a nested dictionary from arrays to lists

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dictionary like this:

```
workersDays=
{'worker1': {datetime.date(2017, 10, 20): array(['1', '3', '64', '56', '34', '23']),
               (datetime.date(2017, 10, 20);array(['12', '34', '56', '78', '98', '45']
worker2: { datetime.date(2017, 10, 21)......................

}
```

i try this:

```
import numpy as np
for worker in workersDays.keys():
        for day in worker:
             worker[day]=worker[day].tolist()
display(workersDays)
```

however the only error i get is:

```
KeyError: '1'
```

any Clue how to change the items inside a nested dictionary fromarrays to lists?

Comment: Your `dict` seems to be not-well formatted

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```py
for key1, value1 in workersDays.items():
    for key2, value2 in value1.items():
        do_this()
        do_that()
```

This way you consider `value1` do be a `dict` and iterate over its own `key` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
for worker in workersDays.keys():
        for day in workersDays[worker].keys():
             workersDays[worker][day]=workersDays[worker][day].tolist()
display(workersDays)
```